# ORA-02267: (column type incompatible with referenced column type) although DATA TYPES ARE IDENTICAL

Tags: sql, oracle, types, foreign-keys, collation

I'm trying to create a table SALESDATA with a composite foreign key of time_id, product_id and customer_id.

I get the error message:

> The data type or collation of the referencing column was incompatible with the data type or collation of the referenced column.

Since the data types of my foreign keys are identical with the primary keys of the referenced tables, I'd like to know what collation is in that context and how that could maybe solve my problem.

Here is the code for reference:

````
create table ach131.TIME(
    time_id NUMBER(*,0),      <----------- those
    orderdate TIMESTAMP,
    primary key(time_id)
);

create table ach131.PRODUCT(
    product_id CHAR(10 BYTE),      <-----------
    p_description CHAR (50 BYTE),
    p_salesprice NUMBER(10,2),
    p_purchaseprice NUMBER(10,2),
    p_category CHAR(10 BYTE),
    p_categorydescription VARCHAR2(45 BYTE),
    p_division VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    p_divisiondescription VARCHAR2(45 BYTE),
    primary key(product_id)
);

create table ach131.SALESORGANISATION(
    customer_id NUMBER(*,0),             <-----------
    s_customerdescription VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    s_city VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    s_salesorganisation VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    s_SOdescription VARCHAR2(45 BYTE),
    s_country VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    primary key(customer_id)
);

create table ach131.SALESDATA(
    time_id NUMBER(*,0),      <----------- are equal to these here
    product_id CHAR(10 BYTE),      <-----------
    customer_id NUMBER(*,0),      <-----------
    revenue NUMBER(10,2),
    salesquantity NUMBER(10,2),
    costgoodssold NUMBER(10,2),
    discount NUMBER(10,2),
    netsales NUMBER(10,2),
    foreign key(time_id) references TIME(time_id),
    foreign key(product_id) references PRODUCT(product_id),
    foreign key(customer_id) references SALESORGANISATION(customer_id)
);```
````

Comment: Unfortunately for you your posted code does not reproduce the error you complain of. [Here is a db<>fiddle which creates all four tables](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5dcb685895a58740487b7154e223cf79). Also, please clarify that `ORA-02267` is the error number you have.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error too, but maybe it's something with `TIME`, Oracle keyword.

Comment: Thank you, APC and Ponder Stibbons.
APC, it's in the description, but you're right, I could've put it in the text for better flow.

Comment: You have used ach131 schema name. Are you creating it from another schema?

Comment: Doh! I missed that it was in the question title (even though I edited it).

Comment: Have you tried declaring the tables with explicit precision instead of using no precision?  I would try declaring the numbers as (38,0) just to see if it gets you past the error.